# Efficient method to check if point is within a diamond

Tags: algorithm

I have an array of diamonds as shown in the image and I know the position of every diamond and the distance from the origin of the diamond to any vertex (They are all the same distance from the center). I am also given a point. Given that information what is the most efficient method to find which diamond the point is in.

I know that I can just check the distance of the point from the position of every diamond but that seems way too cpu intensive as I have to do this multiple times.

[image]

Also, this shouldn't matter, but I am using C# and Unity 3D to do this.

Comment: Have you taken any courses in linear algebra? Also, what's the relative offset between the diamond closest to the origin and the origin?

Comment: Seems like bounding boxes would eliminate all but about 4 diamonds so you only have to do detailed checks for a few cases.

Comment: I am currently taking Pre-Calculus in highschool, and I understand that I can find it out by performing checks on every diamond but that doesn't seem efficient. I was wondering if there was a way to get an answer without performing checks on each diamond. Also assume that I can find the relative offset as I can get the position of any diamond and the origin is (0, 0). Given that offset and the two other things I have mentioned is there anything I can do to get the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your diamonds form a regular pattern as in your picture, then just perform coordinate transformation to rotate the whole thing 45 degrees CW or CCW with (0, 0) as the origin. After that the problem becomes trivial: locating a point in a regular orthogonal grid.

Comment: Oh wow I'm stupid. That makes so much sense. I cant believe I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Diamonds border line have equations

```
x + y = a0 + u * Size
y - x = b0 + v * Size
```

where a0, b0 are coordinates of the some vertex of base diamond (that has cell coordinates 0, 0), u and v are cell coordinates, Size is edge length. So to find what diamond point (px, py) belongs to, you can calculate

```
u = Floor((px + py - a0) / Size))
v = Floor((py - px - b0) / Size))
```